# Unpack into the list append method in Python

Tags: python, unpack, iterable-unpacking

I run into a problem when unpacking a tuple. I want the first value to be appended to a list and a second assigned to a variable. For example:

```
list = []
tuple = (1, 2)

list.append, variable = tuple
```

But this raises an exception since I am assigning to a bultin and not actually calling in. Is that possible in Python? Or even a simpler operation such as:

```
a, b = 5, 4
tuple = (1, 2)

a+, b = tuple
```

to yield `a = 6, b = 2`.

Comment: never name a variable after a builtin, such as list

Comment: You shouldn't use reserved keywords for variable names

Comment: @GaganTK They are not reserved keywords (like `and`, `for` etc.) you *can't* assign to them at all

Comment: Your two examples are rather different from each other. It also feels like you can use clear obvious python syntax to do the operations over a couple of lines- what's wrong with that?

Comment: You can't assign to a function call. I think I can picture a complicated class that would let you write `Thing(lst).append, variable = tuple`, where `Thing(lst)` would have a property named `append` whose setter just calls `lst.append`. But I doubt that would really be worth the effort and overhead. Just write `a, b = t; lst.append(a)`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no brief syntax to allow this. However, here's a class that creates a wrapper around a list, so that assigning to an `append` attribute really calls the underlying list's `append` method. This could be useful if you have a *lot* of values to append to the list.

```
class Appender:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

    # The rare write-only property
    append = property(None, lambda self, v: self.lst.append(v))


values = []
value_appender = Appender(values)

value_appender.append, b = (1,2)
assert values == [1]
```

Perhaps simpler, a subclass of `list` with a similar property:

```
class Appendable(list):
    take = property(None, lambda self, v: self.append(v))

values = Appendable()
values.take, b = (1, 2)
assert values == [1]
```

Comment: Hello, very cool answer! This is pretty trivial but I think that line should read `values = Appendable()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; it's a trivial typo, but it makes big different.

Answer (score 2):

`append` is a method on the builtin `list` type. Python allows tuple unpacking into variables in one line as a convenience, but it won't decide to call the append method with part of your tuple as an argument. Just write your code on multiple lines, that will help make it easier to read too.

```
my_list = []
my_tuple = (1, 2)
a, b = my_tuple
my_list.append(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map function on the append method for the list.

```
>>> a = (6,7)
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list(map(b.append, a))
[None, None]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I am not really sure what the list() does in this statement but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes you could do it in a single line, but I wouldn't.

```
l = []
a = (1,2)
l[:0], b = [[x] if c == 0 else x for c,x in enumerate(a)]
>>> l
[1]
>>> b
2
```

Comment: That prepends, rather than appending.

Comment: `*l[len(l):], b = a` is a little shorter than that (and appends), though still isn't a particularly good idea to actually use, since it's both illegible and slow.